# How to generate multiple text fields for nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following problem:

I want to generate multiple text fields in a form, so that I have the following result in the end:

```
[
  {foo: 0},
  {foo: 1},
  {foo: 10},
  {foo: 11},
  {foo: 100}
]
```

In my form I wrote the following Code:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:foo_associates, @bar.foo_associates) do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_field(:maincompany_id) %>
  <%= ff.text_field(:maincompany_id) %>
  <%= ff.text_field(:maincompany_id) %>
  <%= ff.text_field(:maincompany_id) %>
  <%= ff.text_field(:maincompany_id) %>
<% end %>
```

So the rendered HTML should look like this:

```
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][0][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][1][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][2][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][3][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][4][foo]" />
```

But it looks like this:

```
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][0][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][0][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][0][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][0][foo]" />
<input name="company[foo_associates_attributes][0][foo]" />
```

And my result looks like this:

```
[
  {foo: 0}
]
```

What am I doing wrong?
All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller

```
#new

5.times {@bar.foo_associates.build}
```

In form

```
<%= f.fields_for(:foo_associates) do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_field(:foo) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would also suggest the cocoon gem. It will allow for dynamically building the relationships in the form. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. So you could start with 1 or built associations as @dileepnandanam says, but then you can use the gem to add 3,4,5, etc.

Comment: But when In do IT that way, I can only associate a fixed number of foo_associates with @bar?

Comment: yes @Daniel, just posted the answer to correct the fundamental mistake. you have to use https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon